# AWS GLUE predicate pushdown with variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am looking to utilize predicate pushdown to optimize the reads. I found documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-pushdown.html and this works perfectly if I hardcode the predicate values.

Everytime my AWS Glue runs,I would like to store the DateTime into a value. Then pass that to predicate pushdown so that the next time it runs, awsglue only looks for values after the last execution. May I ask how do you use predicate pushdown with a variable for AWS Glue?

Comment: You can use boto3 api calls to get the last run time of glue job and use it in pushdown predicate. If you want to use the value from the dataframes generated you can use job bookmark feature. If you want to alter value then job bookmark will not work and you need to implement metadata approach where you will be storing your values in data warehouse or S3 location at the end of job run and use it for next glue job run.